# Using dplyr::summarize() function for multi-step arithmetical process?

Tags: r

So I've got some golf data that I'm messing with in R:

```
player  rd  hole    shot    distToPin   distShot
E. Els  1   1       1       525         367.6
E. Els  1   1       2       157.4       130.8
E. Els  1   1       3       27.5        27.4
E. Els  1   1       4       1.2         1.2
E. Els  1   2       1       222         216.6
E. Els  1   2       2       6.8         6.6
E. Els  1   2       3       0.3         0.3
E. Els  2   1       1       378         244.4
E. Els  2   1       2       135.9       141.6
E. Els  2   1       3       6.7         6.9
E. Els  2   1       4       0.1         0.1
```

I'm trying to make an "efficiency" computation.  Basically, I want to compute the following formula (which I made up, if you can't tell) by round:

```
E = hole yardage / (sum(distance of all shots) - hole yardage)
```

And ultimately, I want my results to look like this:

```
            rd      efficiency
E.Els       1       205.25
            2       25.2
```

That `efficiency` column is the averaged result of the efficiency for each hole over the entire round.  The issue that I'm having is I can't quite figure out how to do such a complex calculation using dplyr::summarize():

```
efficiency <- df %>% 
group_by(player, rd) %>%
summarize(efficiency = (sum(distShot) - distToPin))
```

But the problem with that particular script is that it returns the error:

```
Error: expecting a single value
```

I think my problem is that were it to run, it wouldn't be able to tell WHICH distToPin to subtract, and the one I want is obviously the first distToPin of each hole, or the accurate hole length (unfortunately, I don't have a column of just "hole yardage."  I want to pull that first distToPin of each hole out and use it within my summarize() arithmetic.  Is this even possible?

I'm guessing that there is a way to do these types of complex, multi-step calculations within the summarize function,  But maybe there's not!  Any ideas or advice?

Comment: I think it would help to write out all the steps you need to get to your final calculation and then try to write piped code that covers them all. One step that your code doesn't cover but you clearly need is to calculate the distance of each shot so that you can sum those distances by hole in a subsequent step.

Comment: `summarize` is designed to return a single value per aggregate while your formula results in the same size as the original data, thus you should use `mutate` instead. Though it is really unclear what are trying to do.

Comment: I've tinkered with this a little and am realizing that you can't calculate your statistic with the data you've got. For any one player on any one hole, the sum of his or her distances from the pin will always equal the length of the hole, even if he or she hits the ball farther away from the hole on some shots. It always has to get to zero, right? So you would need to observe shot distance directly to get to your efficiency stat.

Comment: Yep!  I'm an idiot.  Updated to include individual shot data -- don't know how I missed that not getting copied over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing some steps. Here is a deliberately labored version to show that, using `dplyr`. It assumes that your data frame is named `golfdf`:

```
golfdf %>%
  group_by(player, round, hole) %>% 
  summarise(hole.length = first(distToPin), shots.length = sum(distShot)) %>%
  group_by(player, round) %>%
  summarise(efficiency = sum(hole.length) / (sum(shots.length) - sum(hole.length)))
```

Comment: Sorry I went dark there for a minute.  Anyway, you're right -- don't know why my shot data didn't copy over, but I edited the OP to include the shot data.

Comment: So the final answer is just the above script minus the two lines of mutate() to create a faux distShot.  If you wanna update the answer, feel free.  I was gonna edit it, but didn't know what to do about all the rest of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I should edit the answer to catch up with the new version of your data. I'll do that in a bit.